# How to create a Visual-studio shortcut "con+tab" for console.log

Tags: visual-studio, shortcut, console.log, code-snippets

how can i create a snippet or shortcut under VISUAL STUDIO so when i write "con"+tab" it edits and completes console.log on Visual Studio

i'd want it to be re usable on every project and files and folders, i'll work on, without further actions
qsmlgkjqsmkfhqjsmldkgjqmlskgfjmqlkjgfl

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.